# Weblogic 10.3.4 jsf 1.2 encodes special characters

Tags: jsf

We have a web application, which uses weblogic jsf 1.2 implementation from deployable-libraries(jsf-1.2.war). We started to use weblogic jsf impl after having some problems with compatibility of packed jsf-impl and weblogic 10.3.**4**.

So the problem is that, we have outputLink with several params, these params' values could contain spacial chars, so we explicitly encode them(we have taglib function for this purpose), but  jsf impl on  weblogic 10.3.**4** also encodes these chars, so we have double encoded link URL. Does anybody know is there a possibility to disable this option on weblogic and encode params only manually.

Answer (score 3):

Just do **not** encode it yourself with a custom taglib. The `<f:param>` will already implicitly do it.

```html
<h:outputLink value="page.jsf">
    <h:outputText value="Click" />
    <f:param name="foo" value="#{bean.foo}" />
    <f:param name="bar" value="#{bean.bar}" />
</h:outputLink>
```

That's all. The `#{bean.foo}` and `#{bean.bar}` in above example can just return the raw and unencoded string value.

---

**Update** as per the comments, this suggests that those two servers JBoss AS 4.2.3 and WebLogic 10.3.2 are using a specific JSF implementation/version which exposes a bug in URL-encoding of `<f:param>`. As far, I can only find the following related reports (it's not clear if you're using MyFaces or Mojarra, so I searched in both):

- Mojarra (a.k.a. Sun RI): http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-791 fixed in 1.2_10.
- MyFaces: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MYFACES-1832 fixed in 1.1.6 and > 1.2.2(?).

I recommend to replace/upgrade the JSF version of the servers in question to a newer version than the ones mentioned in those reports, or to ship JSF libraries along with the webapp itself and add `web.xml` context parameters to instruct the server to use the webapp bundled JSF instead.

Comment: Thank you. I need encoded value. The problem is in different behavior of application servers - jboss 423 and weblogic 1032 does nod encode f:param, but weblogic 1034 encodes. I've tried to stop explicitly encode params, but - no luck- we just have a rendered link with url, which contains special characters, instaed of encoded ones(the same behavior for jboss 423 and weblogic 1032). I looked at weblogic 1032 and 1034 implementations of OutputLinkRenderer and 1032 does not encode spec. chars, when 1034 - encodes them. Maybe, there is a possibility to disable somehow auto encoding on weblogic 103

Comment: @Yigak Your 'answer' was a little too long to fit as a comment, and was truncated. Fortunately, BalusC can see the original. In the future, please use _comments_ when commenting on answers, and try to fit within the limit. If it's too big to be a comment, it should probably be an edit to your question.